# Pronunciation of words such as "hot" and "stop"

Tags: american-english, british-english

I would like to ask how to pronounce the o sound in words like *hot, stop* in AE and BE.

I noticed that BE's pronunciation is different from AE's for these words.

According to Cambridge University online dictionary, *hot* is pronounced in BE as /hɒt/, so h + o (just like the letter) + t. But in AE it is pronounced /hɑːt/, which is like "hut" or h + u + o + t, or h + o + u + t, where the u is pronounced as in *hut*.

Comment: Yes. Good perception.

Comment: No. The sound is variable in AE. I've heard /ɑ/, /ɒ/, /ɔ/, and in fact you'll find early 20th century British novelists representing the American pronunciation as <hawt>, suggesting they heard it as /ɔ:/ - but except under exaggerated stress it's never a diphthong, even in the South where we tend to diphthongalize almost everything.

Comment: @StoneyB: There are words, like *dog* and *coffee,* where the British /ɒ/ becomes an American /ɔ/, which is often pronounced in New York City as a diphthong. (But not *hot* and *stop,* which are /ɑ/ in New York City.) elegant: Are you sure it was *hot* and *stop* that you heard as a diphthong, and not a word with /ɒ/ which turns into /ɔ/ in America, like *moss* or *cloth*? For an exaggerated version of this accent, listen to the Saturday Night Live routine *"Coffee Talk"* (both words in the title are pronounced with that diphthong).

Comment: What is your question? You have shown what you have found out, but what are you still confused about?

Comment: To me, the American pronunciation sounds like a long, rising letter *a* sound. That makes the words *hot* and *stop* sound like *haA-t* and *staA-p*, in American accents.

Comment: @PeterShor Hmm ... I know the inglide 'dwog', but I think of that and *coffee* as belonging to the THOUGHT phoneme, not the LOT. But I am surprised to read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City_English#Vowels) that "a subset of words with /ɒ/ as in *lot* feature a lengthened and diphthongized variant, [ɑə]." That'll teach me to never say never again.

Comment: I am putting this on hold per nxx's comment. What is your question? You read a dictionary entry and noticed what it said. That is fine, but where do we come in? The rest of your post deals with translating a rather precise IPA notation we can understand into some imprecise ad-hoc thingamajig of your personal invention. I am not quite sure what the purpose of that exercise is. /ɑː/ is not like "u + o" at all, otherwise IPA would just say "u + o" and not bother with inventing /ɑː/. If you are not sure how to pronounce /ɒ/ or /ɑː/, please [look it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA).

Comment: New York and Boston are not like Americans in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that BE's pronunciation is different than AE's in this word

You're right. They are not pronounced in the same way. English and other British pronunciation involves an *O* sound that is different in North American (American and Canadian) English but, is part of other languages.

How to pronounce that sound will depend on which English you speak. You can hear recordings and see pronunciation symbols for American and English pronunciations of the words *hot* and *stop*, here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/hot_1?q=hot# and here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/stop_1?q=stop#.

Comment: so can we say in the US and Canada ,  the word hot  mostly is pronounced like 

h u u t = h a a t    ( u is in the word hut )

or

h u w t = h a w t    ( u is in the word hut )

or

h u ə t               ( u is in the word hut )  



by the way
what are the words whose phonetic writings is written with  /ɔ:/

thank you

Comment: I don't know phonetic/pronunciation symbols. I can do my best to describe pronunciations in normal letters. From my, English and British perspective, it seems that in North American pronunciation, the letter *o* in the word *hot* is usually pronounced with a long, rising letter *a* sound. That makes it sound like *haA-t*.

Comment: Your spelling pronunciations are pretty meaningless, because the vowel of *hut* is pronounced in several different ways by different dialects in the U.S. and the U.K. There is indeed one common pronunciation of *hut* in the U.K. which is sort of a short version of a common pronunciation of *hot* in the U.S. You are going to have to learn IPA to have a meaningful discussion of pronunciation.

Comment: Peter Shor, there is also a pronunciation of *hut*, in the UK, that involves pronouncing the letter *u* in it, like the *u* in the words *full* and *push*. That is less common. My descriptions of pronunciations in normal letters, were intended to express what North American pronunciation in this context, sounds like to me. I think they were sufficient.

Comment: @Tristan r: the descriptions of the pronunciation sound pretty good. But if the OP is hearing a diphthong, he's possibly been talking to somebody from New York City, where they pronounce this vowel different from most Americans.

Comment: Peter, I'll accept that. Not being American, I'm not an expert on all aspects of, American use of the language.